# Make buttons when pressed read text from a .txt file and display it (Python)

Tags: python, button, text

```
def createDice():

    mainMenu.destroy()

    global createMenu
    createMenu = tkinter.Tk()
    createMenu.title("Dice Maker.")

    global lblName
    global entName
    global lblPassword
    global entPassword
    global lblOutcomes
    global entOut1
    global entOut2
    global entOut3
    global entOut4
    global entOut5
    global entOut6
    global btnConfirm

    lblName = tkinter.Label(createMenu, text="What would you like to call your dice? Dont put .(file type) at the end.")
    entName = tkinter.Entry(createMenu)
    lblPassword = tkinter.Label(createMenu, text="If you would like a password in order\n to use your dice, enter one.")
    entPassword = tkinter.Entry(createMenu)
    lblOutcomes = tkinter.Label(createMenu, text="Enter the outcomes for the dice, the bottom one is outcome 6.")

    entOut1 = tkinter.Entry(createMenu)
    entOut2 = tkinter.Entry(createMenu)
    entOut3 = tkinter.Entry(createMenu)
    entOut4 = tkinter.Entry(createMenu)
    entOut5 = tkinter.Entry(createMenu)
    entOut6 = tkinter.Entry(createMenu)
    btnConfirm = tkinter.Button(createMenu, text="Confirm", command=createDice2)

    lblName.pack()
    entName.pack()
    lblPassword.pack()
    entPassword.pack()
    lblOutcomes.pack()
    entOut1.pack()
    entOut2.pack()
    entOut3.pack()
    entOut4.pack()
    entOut5.pack()
    entOut6.pack()
    btnConfirm.pack()

def createDice2():

    global name
    global nameTxt
    global password
    global out1
    global out2
    global out3
    global out4
    global out5
    global out6

    name = entName.get()
    nameTxt = name + ".txt"
    password = entPassword.get()
    out1u = entOut1.get()
    out2u = entOut2.get()
    out3u = entOut3.get()
    out4u = entOut4.get()
    out5u = entOut5.get()
    out6u = entOut6.get()

    out1 = out1u + "\n"
    out2 = out2u + "\n"
    out3 = out3u + "\n"
    out4 = out4u + "\n"
    out5 = out5u + "\n"
    out6 = out6u + "\n"

    f = open(nameTxt, 'w')
    f.write(out1)
    f.write(out2)
    f.write(out3)
    f.write(out4)
    f.write(out5)
    f.write(out6)
    f.write(password)
    f.close()

    createMenu.destroy()
    restartpls = tkinter.Tk()
    restartpls.title("Restart this program")

    lblrestart = tkinter.Label(restartpls, text="Please restart this program, this is needed so that\n the program can see that you have created\n a new dice.")
    lblrestart.pack()

    restartpls.mainloop()
    sys.exit()

def loadDice():
 #see the other .txt files around the python file and make a button for each of them.
 #other code i will do.

def mainMenu():
    global mainMenu
    mainMenu = tkinter.Tk()
    mainMenu.title("Menu")

    btnCreateDice = tkinter.Button(mainMenu, text="Create Dice", command=createDice)
    btnLoadDice = tkinter.Button(mainMenu, text="Load Dice")
    btnExit = tkinter.Button(mainMenu, text="Exit", command=exit)

    btnCreateDice.pack()
    btnLoadDice.pack()
    btnExit.pack()

    mainMenu.mainloop()
mainMenu()
```

When you run this code it will ask you to either create a dice, exit or load a dice. I have coded the create a dice and exit button program. I can't figure out how to make python create a button for each of the .txt file/s in the same folder as it and put it in a button/s. Then when a specific button is pressed it will put the first 6 lines of code into the outputs for a dice and the 7th line into a password.

**how to make python create a button for each of the .txt file/s in the same folder as it and put it in a button/s**

I'm putting this code at the def loadDice(): at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic example of how to do this, using globals and without preserving the button objects (as they are only defined locally). I've put the buttons in a frame so you can pack the buttons after the Load Dice Button but before the Exit Button. I've made it global for simplicity of the example, since `mainMenu` is already global, but I've also included a commented out example of how you can use `functools.partial` to pass parameters to button commands.

```
import glob
import functools
import os

... the rest of your code

def loadDice():
    for dice_file_name in glob.glob('*.txt'):
        print(dice_file_name)
        btnDie = tkinter.Button(frameCustomDice, text=os.path.splitext(dice_file_name)[0])
        btnDie.pack()
    mainMenu.update()

def mainMenu():
    global mainMenu
    mainMenu = tkinter.Tk()
    mainMenu.title("Menu")

    global frameCustomDice
    frameCustomDice = tkinter.Frame(height=2, bd=1, relief=tkinter.SUNKEN)

    btnCreateDice = tkinter.Button(mainMenu, text="Create Dice", command=createDice)
    btnLoadDice = tkinter.Button(mainMenu, text="Load Dice", command=loadDice)
    # btnLoadDice = tkinter.Button(mainMenu, text="Load Dice", command=functools.partial(loadDice, mainMenu, frameCustomDice))
    btnExit = tkinter.Button(mainMenu, text="Exit", command=exit)

    btnCreateDice.pack()
    btnLoadDice.pack()
    frameCustomDice.pack()
    btnExit.pack()

    mainMenu.mainloop()

mainMenu()
```

From this point, some points to consider:

- Try and avoid using the `global` variables if possible, by passing the necessary variables to your commands as parameters.
- use `functools.partial` to provide a custom parameterized command for each of the buttons created in `loadDice`, either by passing the file name to some function (say `rollDice`), or parsing the probabilities of the sides of the dice from the file, in `loadDice`, and passing those probabilities to `rollDice` as parameters.
- track the loaded buttons, currently if you run `loadButton` twice, it will load the buttons again. I think you can either remove all buttons from the frame first, or save some data about what buttons are loaded, and check this before loading a new button.

Comment: Thanks for the help.